# Draytek Vigor router problem with Apple Mac

Tags: mac, router, wireless-networking

A few weeks ago a Vigor 2820n router was installed at a customers site, to replace a faulty Belkin router which had faulty LAN ports causing problems for the EPOS system we supplied.

Since then the customer has had problems accessing sites like Google Calendar and Yahoo using Apple Mac laptops connected using wireless or LAN. We have tested the these sites using a laptop running Microsoft Windows, without any problems.

We asked the customer to test the Apple Mac laptops with the original Belkin router and they reported there was no problems.

Are there any router settings which would cause these problems or could there be a incompatibility between the wireless in the the router and the Apple Macs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the DNS settings between the routers, and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the customer has replaced the router with another make which fixed the problem.  I did not get chance to test your solution, but I have accepted your answer.